# Prove this equality about condition numbers $\frac{1}{{\rm cond}(A)_2}=\frac{\lambda}{\|A\|_2}$

Tags: matrices, condition-number, spectral-norm

I am supposed to prove this equality. Let $A$ be an invertible square matrix over $\mathbb R$

$$\frac{1}{{\rm cond}(A)_2}=\frac{\lambda}{\|A\|_2}$$

where ${\rm cond}({}\cdot{})_2$ is the condition number w.r.t. the $2$-norm. And $\lambda$ is defined as

$$\lambda=\inf\|B\|_2$$

where the infimum is taken over all $B$ such that $B+A$ becomes not invertible.

I was able to work out one side. Let $B$ be as above, then $A+B=(I+BA^{-1})A$ is not invertible $\implies I+BA^{-1}$ is not invertible $\implies1\leqslant\|BA^{-1}\|_2\leqslant\|B\|_2\ \|A^{-1}\|_2$. Now take the infimum over all possible $B$ we get
$$1/\|A^{-1}\|_2\leqslant\lambda\implies \frac{1}{{\rm cond}(A)_2}\leqslant\frac{\lambda}{\|A\|_2}$$

Now for the other side I guess I am supposed to find a sequence of such $B$ to approach the equality. But I can't seem to succeed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cond}{\operatorname{cond}}$
You have $\cond(A)_2=\frac{\sigma_\max}{\sigma_\min}$ and $\|A\|_2=\sigma_\max$,
where the $\sigma$ are the singular values of $A$.
 This means you need to find a matrix $B$ so that $\|B\|_2=\sigma_\min$. One matrix with that property that comes to mind is $B=u_\min\sigma_\min v_\min^\top$, where $u_k$, $v_k$ are the left and right singular vectors in the SVD 
$$
A=U\Sigma V^\top=\sum_k u_k\sigma_k v_k^\top.
$$
Then $A-B$ has a rank deficiency of one, thus is singular, and $\|B\|_2=\sigma_\min\|u_\min\|\,\|v_\min\|=\sigma_\min$.